# Operator or formal definition of mirroring the image of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x \in [0,1]$. Define $f(x) = x$. The function $g(x) = 1 - x$ is a mirrored image of $f$ at the symmetric point $x = 0.5$.
Is there a formal notation for that exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want $g$ to be the reflection of $f$ about the line $x = a$ then you want $g(2a-x) = f(x)$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f$, because the midpoint of $x$ and $2a-x$ is $a$. To get a formal definition of the reflection operator, you just need to figure out the domain of $g$, which would be the reflection of the domain of $f$, and then you can define say $reflect(f)(x) = f(\cdots)$ for every $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and function $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \cdots$. I'll leave you to fill in the blanks.

Comment: So is refelction the proper term to mirror the image of some function at some vertical line? Actually I just want to know how you would call this mirroring?

Comment: @clueless: Oh yes just "reflection about a line" would be the proper term for it. Before seeing your comment I was for a moment wondering whether you really want to see the formal operator definition but I see that's not needed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_transformation for more transformations and their common names. The simplest ones you probably should look at for now are affine transformations.

Comment: @clueless: By the way it's slightly misleading to say "mirror ... at the symmetric **point** $x = 0.5$" since it is a line not a point. Reflecting about a point is in fact the same as a 180 degree rotation about that point.

Comment: @clueless:You're welcome!